# Replace a NULL value to Not Set if another column is NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm making a parameter of salespeople and I need a NULL value in the SalesID column but it needs to say Not Set in the Display name column. There are NULL values in the Display but they have SalesID that I want to use instead.

```sql
SELECT SalesID, 
ISNULL(DisplayName, SalesID) AS DisplayName
FROM SalesTable
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help explain what you want to do.  Also, you should add an appropriate database tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use case when and COALESCE()

```
SELECT SalesID, 
case when DisplayName is null and  SalesID is null then 'Not Set' 
 else COALESCE(DisplayName,SalesID) end AS DisplayName
FROM SalesTable
```

Comment: That shows the same information. I need DisplayName to display 'Not Set' if both SalesID and DisplayName are Null, while keeping SalesID Null.

Answer (score 1):

Considering you are using SQL SERVER, You can extend COALESCE function -

```
SELECT SalesID, 
COALESCE(DisplayName, SalesID, 'Not Set') AS DisplayName
FROM SalesTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT SalesID, 
       COALESCE(DisplayName, 'Not Set') AS DisplayName
FROM SalesTable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SalesID, 
CASE WHEN (DisplayName IS NULL AND  SalesID IS NULL) THEN 'Not Set' ELSE DisplayName END AS DisplayName
FROM SalesTable
```